# Save and Load models from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, h2o

Any way to allow an H2O cluster to save/load directly to S3?

```
model.save('s3n://my-domain/gbm-from-the-future')
model.load('s3n://my-domain/gbm-from-the-future')
```

Historically, I have achieved this by:
- Saving to a file-system off of the Cluster
- Syncing with S3
- Downloading from S3
- Loading from the file-system

Obviously, there has to be a better way from the cluster itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Python [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=save_model#h2o.save_model) for `h2o.save_model()` this is already supported (you did not mention which of the APIs you are using, so I am using Python as an example). Have you tried putting an S3 address in the file location argument of the standard model save and load functions?  If you find that this is not working, please file a bug report on the H2O [JIRA](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV/).